# How to explain this selector

Tags: jquery

How to explain this statment

```
var a = $(this);
```

What will 'a' contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, [it depends](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/).

According to the article, depending on where this line of code exists, *this* can be either a DOM object or a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on context it's being used in. In this instance:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var a = $(this);
    });
});
```

This bit of code loops through all the `<a>` tags on a page and on each loop, `$(this)` will be the current `<a>` tag. You can use all the jquery methods on that object. In this case `a` is just a link to `$(this)`. So, instead of doing, for instance, `$(this).hide()` you can now do `a.hide()`.

This is very basic jquery.  You should find a nice beginners tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

In this code, $(this) will refer to the clicked button element. It's meaning depends on the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

`a` will reference a *jQuery* object of the object referenced by `this`. See the [manual page about the `jQuery` object](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope. `$(this)` gives you a jQueryified object that is based on whatever `this` is.

Answer (score 0):

That depends inside which function is that called, for example:

```
$("input#hello").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

In that case, $(this) will be the input selected by the locator outside of the function.